# How and why do they redirect their robots.txt file to their homepage on their site?

Tags: robots.txt

A `robots.txt` file is usually just a text file under your site root directory. For example, you can view `www.amazon.com/robots.txt`. But today, I found a website with a strange `robots.txt` file. If you just type

```
http://xli.bugs3.com/robots.txt
```

it does not show a text file, instead it still shows the home page of that site. 
How could it happen and why does the webmaster do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a fairly conventional/basic server setup, where it is just files as you say, it could simply be a [htaccess redirect rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess). The rule might be something like "serve a file if it's on the server, otherwise just serve the index".

Or it might be an application server like Rails, where there's no direct relationship between the server directory structure and URL pathnames.